# Quarkus docker build is failing

Tags: java, docker, quarkus

We have been trying to deploy quarkus build image to ECR but recently been hitting

```
error: Error -1 running transaction
The command '/bin/sh -c microdnf install curl ca-certificates ${JAVA_PACKAGE}     && microdnf update     && microdnf clean all     && mkdir /deployments     && chown 1001 /deployments     && chmod "g+rwX" /deployments     && chown 1001:root /deployments     && curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/fabric8/run-java-sh/${RUN_JAVA_VERSION}/run-java-sh-${RUN_JAVA_VERSION}-sh.sh -o /deployments/run-java.sh     && chown 1001 /deployments/run-java.sh     && chmod 540 /deployments/run-java.sh     && echo "securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom" >> /etc/alternatives/jre/lib/security/java.security' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

With the command docker build -f /src/main/docker/Dockerfile.jvm -t app:latest .

Here is the docker file

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.1

ARG JAVA_PACKAGE=java-11-openjdk-headless
ARG RUN_JAVA_VERSION=1.3.8

ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en'

# Install java and the run-java script
# Also set up permissions for user `1001`
RUN microdnf install curl ca-certificates ${JAVA_PACKAGE} \
    && microdnf update \
    && microdnf clean all \
    && mkdir /deployments \
    && chown 1001 /deployments \
    && chmod "g+rwX" /deployments \
    && chown 1001:root /deployments \
    && curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/fabric8/run-java-sh/${RUN_JAVA_VERSION}/run-java-sh-${RUN_JAVA_VERSION}-sh.sh -o /deployments/run-java.sh \
    && chown 1001 /deployments/run-java.sh \
    && chmod 540 /deployments/run-java.sh \
    && echo "securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom" >> /etc/alternatives/jre/lib/security/java.security

# Configure the JAVA_OPTIONS, you can add -XshowSettings:vm to also display the heap size.
ENV JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"

COPY target/lib/* /deployments/lib/
COPY target/*-runner.jar /deployments/app.jar

EXPOSE 8080
USER 1001

ENTRYPOINT [ "/deployments/run-java.sh" ]
```

Comment: Could you paste the Dockerfile? This error doesn't say much

Comment: updated the question to contain the dockerfile content

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error couple of days ago on a working project w/o changing any configurations. Just started failing. On my side managed to fix the problem after updating

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.1
```

to

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.3
```

in the Dockerfile.jvm

Answer (score 0):

@isolona's solution worked on our project too. Upgrading from ubi-minimal:8.1 to ubi-minimal:8.3 for the base image fixed it.